# Is there no way of including font color when returning data using IMPORTRANGE or VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets

I know these functions don't normally work this way, but this is the only option I can think of with what I need to accomplish. Just please if anyone knows of a way that importrange can also display even just the font color from the source sheet (cell fill doesn't matter), that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately no. `IMPORTRANGE` is not capable to carry on the formatting. but you can copy-paste it by clicking on the red circle and:

[image]

Comment: I would not have asked here if the solution to what I was asking was this simple, but thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets considers formulas and raw data to simply be values inside the cells, and it considers formatting to be visual prettiness for people. So, there's no formula which can affect a format, nor is there a format which can affect a cell's formula/data.

However, you can use Conditional Formatting to automatically format a wide range of cells in various ways. If your goal is to have this spreadsheet apply format to itself automatically based on its cells' values, this is probably what you want.

[image: Google Sheets: The Format menu, with the Conditional Formatting option highlighted][image: Google Sheets: The Conditional Formatting inspector, showing a gradient from green to yellow to red across all cells in the D column]

As a plus, the "Paste format" button works with Conditional Formatting too!